# Observium Upgrade procedure on ubuntu 14.04 from Community edition to prefessional edition

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I am planning to upgrade observium from community edition to professional edition.
Can someone please help with the procedure.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```